# How to get the coefficients in a parametric cubic function

Tags: functions, parametric, interpolation, cubics

Let's say I have 4 points with x and y coordinates. And I want to determine the parametric cubic function:
$x(t) = a_x t^3 + b_x t^2 + c_x t^3 + d_x$ and $y(t) = a_y t^3 + b_y t^2 + c_y t^3 + d_y$

So, how can I determine the 8 coefficients $ a_x, b_x, c_x, d_x, a_y, b_y, c_y, d_y $ from those 4 points. Is it similar to estimation of 4 coefficients $ a, b, c, d $ in the cubic polynom?

Comment: This is not clear.  Given four points $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$ we can find a cubic $p(x)$ which interpolates them.  In that case $(x, p(x))$ would seem to fit your requirements.  Obviously, that is not the only solution.  What more would you want?

Comment: To be a little clearer on your problem: For each point you have an equation for the $x$ value and a separate equation for the $y$ value. So you have $8$ equations and the $8$ unknowns of the coefficients $a_x, \dots, a_y,\dots$. But those are not the only unknowns. Each point corresponds to some particular value of $t$. Thus you have four more uknowns $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$ which give the four points. So you currently have $8$ equations to solve for $12$ unknowns. You need four more equations, perhaps just from picking values for $t_i$ as Xaver suggests, or maybe from additional information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify at which time $t_1$ you want to be at the first point, at which time $t_2$ you want to be at the second point, at which time $t_3$ you want to be at the third point, and at which time $t_4$ you want to be at the fourth point. Typically, you will choose this values to fulfill $0=t_1<t_2<t_3<t_4=1$. For example, you could choose $t_1=0, t_2=\frac{1}{3}, t_3=\frac{2}{3}, t_4=1$.

By inserting $x_n, y_n, t_n$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ in the equations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, you get 8 equations with 8 variables ($a_x, b_x, c_x, d_x, a_y, b_y, c_y, d_y$). So you have a system of linear equations which you need to solve in order to get the values for your parameters.